# How to set up git over http?

Tags: git, apache, http, git-http-backend

I need to set up a git server with git-over-http (smart http), but the resources available online are a mess, mixing in other apache configuration, missing details or not being explicit enough.

I am answering this question myself based on what I found lacking in the available resources.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First it is necessary to understand that there are 2 components to git-over-http: git and apache. These two are connected through a script with the name of git-http-backend. The challenge is to configure the interface between these two components, so that http requests to git are forwarded by apache.

**Note:** Security is outside the scope of this guide.

1. Start out by installing git and apache2 using the package manager of your distribution.
2. Add the modules needed by apache to enable git-over-http. These are cgi, alias and env

```bash
$ a2enmod cgi alias env
```

3. Copy the following into `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` (without removing whatever else it contains)

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /data/git
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
    ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
        info/refs | \
        objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
        [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
        pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
        git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
        "/usr/lib/git/git-http-backend/$1"
    Alias /git /data/git
    <Directory /usr/lib/git>
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

4. Now replace the 2 occurrences of `/data/git` with the parent directory of your git repos on the server (don't worry if you don't have any repos yet, just use the directory where you intend to place it/them)

Also replace `/usr/lib/git/git-http-backend` with the location of git-http-backend on your system, which can be found using `$ find / -name git-http-backend`

It may be that on your system `REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER` actually overwrites a valid `REMOTE_USER`. If this setup doesn't work when finished, try removing that line.

According to [this](http://blog.coffeebeans.at/?p=734) source, it may be necessary to replace the last two lines within the Directory tag by `Require all granted` **for apache 2.4** and above.

5. Restart the apache server: `$ apache2ctl -k graceful`

Now the apache server is set up, but we're not done yet, there are some important parts of setting up the repos that will affect whether this setup works or not.

6. Set up the repo:

```bash
$ mkdir myrepo.git
$ cd myrepo.git
$ git init --bare --shared
$ cp hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
$ git update-server-info
$ chown -R wwwrun:www
```

Here it is important to understand that the last line changes the owner of the repo to the apache2 user. This user may be different on your system. To find the apache user, execute `$ ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`. Then to find the group name of the user, execute `$ id user-name`. On my system the user is **wwwrun** and the group **www**. Replace accordingly.

7. Use the repo

In order to use the repo, you need to know the url. For this setup the url is http://server.domain/myrepo.git

Note: http**s** will not work.

When accessing the repo from a client, you just add it as a remote:

```bash
$ git remote add origin http://server.domain/myrepo.git
```

Then you can interact with it like any other git repo.

Comment: Many thanks for this! It worked for me in my ubuntu 14.04 with apache 2.4.7! Some details, my apache user is www-data, in step 6 a '.' is missing at the end for command "chown ...". And git is located in my ubuntu in the folder '/usr/lib/git-core'

Comment: I tried same thing, But it seems some permission issue. I get 403 (unable to access) when I try to clone

Comment: Works great except it doesn't prompt for any authentication. Do you just setup basic auth for that in Apache ?

Comment: I did this a long time ago, and ended up with a paid solution instead, so I can't answer your question. Hope you figure it out

Comment: If you're doing this in CentOS and can't seem to make any progress - double check your iptables rules. CentOS has everything locked down by default. Also, you probably need to modify your SELinux settings for the .htpasswd file if you're following the Git documentation.

Comment: To follow up what Morgan G has said Ubuntu does the same thing, I was testing my hook script my writing to /tmp, when the expected results did not appear I assumed the hook was not working.

Its only reducing the number of web servers instances to one and applying strace  to that process did I discover what was going on.

Comment: "Also replace /usr/lib/git/git-http-backend" and here it should be added that the <Directory> clause must be updated as well. I have it at /usr/libexec/git-core on Gentoo for example.

Comment: Recent Ubuntu seems to have a problem with this.  The git-http-backend causes http 503, resolution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65039313/1364242

Comment: Sadly, didn't work for me. git clone always reports repo not found.

Answer (score 4):

**Multiples projects with differents access rigths**

There is gitolite, but complex... 
A simple solution is to create macro in apache2 conf as :

```
## Git root

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /opt/gitroot
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf

##  SMART Http

ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Directory "/usr/libexec/git-core*">
   Options +ExecCGI +Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Macro Project $repository $developers $users>
    <LocationMatch "^/git/$repository.*$">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        AuthUserFile /opt/basic_auth
        Require $developers $users 
    </LocationMatch>
    <LocationMatch "^/git/$repository/git-receive-pack$">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        AuthUserFile /opt/basic_auth
        Require  $developers
    </LocationMatch>
 </Macro>

 IncludeOptional /opt/git_access.conf
```

And in /opt/git_access.conf

```
Use Project test1 "admin john" "mike"
Use Project test2 "admin emma" "all granted"
```

So, the git project test1 will have read/write access by admin and john, and read only access by mike.

The project test2 will have read access by all authentified users.

The git_access.conf can be produced by your tools from a database of yours projetcs and users for example, and reload by a "service httpd reload".

For the same config for gitweb read access, add in /etc/gitweb.conf :

```
$export_auth_hook = sub {
        my $repo = shift;
        my $user = $cgi->remote_user;
        if($repo =~ s/\/opt\/gitroot\///) {
           open FILE, '/opt/git_access'; 
           while(<FILE>) {
               if ($_ =~ m/Use Project $repo \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\"/)
                {
                    my $users = $1 . ' ' . $2;
                    $users =~ s/all granted/$user/;
                    $users =~ s/user//;
                    if ( $users =~ m/$user/ ) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }              
            }
        }
        return 0;
};
```

This little gitweb hook hide (return 0) the git repositories with no read access for current user.

And into apache2 configuration, the classic gitweb conf :

```
## Gitweb  

Alias /gitweb /var/www/git

<Directory /var/www/git>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +FollowSymlinks 
    AllowOverride None    
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    AuthUserFile /opt/basic_auth
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

That's my config.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for this. 1 thing, where you require the users...
`Require $developer $user` 
`Require $developer`
Just missing the **user** word.
`Require user $developer $user`

Or I guess the **user** word could also be added to the git_access.conf so that you could use Require all granted still.