# Setting Up git-http-backend with apache 2.4

Tags: git, apache2.4, git-http-backend

Im trying to set up a git server using git-http-backend and apache 2.4  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734933/how-to-set-up-git-over-http) about the same thing which was helpful, but I'm still reaching a point where I'm stuck.

I've installed git and apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04 and added the needed modules using

`sudo a2enmod cgi alias env`

Then added the following snippet in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
    ScriptAliasMatch \
      "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
          info/refs | \
          objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
          [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
          pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
          git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
      "/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1"
    Alias /git /var/www/git
    <Directory /usr/lib/git-core>
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that `/var/www/git` is where I intend my repos to go, and running

`find / -name git-http-backend` shows `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend`

Next, inside of `/var/www/git/` I created a directory `myrepo.git` and set it up as such:

```
sudo git init --bare --shared
sudo cp hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
sudo git update-server-info
```

Next, I have to change the ownership of the directory to the apache2 owner (Im told).  Running `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` returns the following:

```
root 3087 0.0 0.4 73688  4928 ? Ss 02:37 0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3455 0.0 0.5 362836  5852 ? Sl 03:13 0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 3456 0.0 0.5 362836  5852 ? Sl 03:13 0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
git 3531 0.0 0.0 14512 932 pts/1 S+ 03:19 0:00 grep -E --color=auto (apache|httpd)
```

Now I'm not sure, because it looks like both `root` and `www-data` are running something, but I have currently decided to set the ownership to www-data (maybe it should be root?).  www-data's group is also www-data (I think)

```
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

so I use that to set ownership:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

I also seem to remember reading that the whole path has to belong to the apache user so just for good measure I set

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Now from my localmachine I am trying to clone the myrepo:

```
git clone http://<ip-address>/myrepo.git
```

And I am getting the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://<ip-address>/myrepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 503
```

Can anybody see what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Recent Ubuntu seems to have a problem with this.  The git-http-backend causes http 503, resolution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65039313/1364242

Answer (score 0):

```
Alias /git /var/www/git
```

That should mean your urls should include /git in it:

```
git clone http://<ip-address>/git/myrepo.git
```

I don't see such an alias in this [Apache configuration](https://gist.github.com/karmi/484199#file-git-hosting-apache-conf-L55-L68)

Comment: Yeah, I copied that Alias from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26734934/3486338) Im not sure that it's necessary.  I think the main problem is a permissions issue though, I changed the directory ownership to `root` and now Im able to clone it but I cant push back up.  I think its similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)