# convert git server from ssh to smart-http; ubuntu, apache; "Not a git repository " error

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu, server, smart-http

I'm trying to convert a git repo from ssh access to smart-http access.
I've found all sorts of old, contradictory advice; the most recent being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734933/how-to-set-up-git-over-http).

My client `.git/config` had the following URL originally:

```
url = git@my-domain:/path-to-repos/my-project.git
```

I've changed that to:

```
url = https://my-domain/my-project.git
```

When I issue the command (works fine with the git@url above):

```
git remote -v show origin
```

the apache server shows the following:

```
==> error.log <==
Not a git repository: '/path-to-repos/my-project.git'
==> access.log <==
a.b.c.d - - [12/Mar/2022:05:47:19 +0000] "GET /my-project.git/info/refs?service=
git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 4851 "-" "git/2.30.0"
```

repos are set   `drwxrwx--- git www-data`

apache has mod  `cgi`, `alias`, `env` enabled

apache site config file has:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /path-to-repos
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
    info/refs | \
    objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
    [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
    pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
    "/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1"
Alias /git /path-to-repos
<Directory /usr/lib/git-core>
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The URL might be  https://my-domain/git/my-project.git?

Comment: unfortunately, just changes the error: Not a git repository: '/path-to-repos/git/my-project.git'

Comment: Ugh.  My mistake.  The main repo directory had the wrong permissions.  Probably because I did the chgrp from the repo itself, not its parent.  I would have bet money I checked that, but apparently only checked the ones below.

Answer (score 0):

I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40925595/6309) that `Alias /git ...` means the HTTPS URL will include `/git`.

But as in my old post, the issue is [one of permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448326/6309):

```sh
cd /path/to/repo.git
sudo chgrp -R groupname .
sudo chmod -R g+rwX .
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' +
```

Comment: Thanks, my fingers hit '*' instead of '.', and I forgot to check the root dir when investigating, as mentioned above.  I've got a followup problem but will post a new question, as the subject is different.